# jQuery live event replacing inner HTML on anchor tag

Tags: jquery

I have the following which works but when the user presses 'more' `<a>` tag (although styled as a button) it then puts a loading gif inside it but from the time the user clicks the button to when the image appears is noticeable. Almost 1 second which makes it look ugly.

It looks like it removes the inner HTML has a think and then populates the image. Could it be its taking time finding the image or something?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        /* <![CDATA[ */
        $(document).ready(function() {

            $('#blogEntryList #moreLink').live("click", function() {

                $(this).html("<img src='../../Content/_layout/images/ajax-loader.gif' />");

                return false;
            });

        });
        /* ]]> */           
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If thats all the code, then looks likely that its taking time to serve up the image.

Would be better to load the image as hidden, and then just show/hide when needed

Comment: How do I do that so I hide the button then show the image without it jumping? eg/when i do the click i hide the a tag and then show the image because at the moment

Comment: Something like this: 
<div id="blogEntryList">
<span id="moreLink">More...</span><img ID="moreWait" src=..(etc) style="display:none" />
</div>
Then:
    $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#blogEntryList #moreLink').live("click", function() {

                $('#moreLink').hide();
                $('#moreWait').show();
            });
        });